# Graph theory radius and diameter

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for every two integers $r\leq s\leq 2r$ there exists $G$, a connected graph, such that $\mathrm{rad}(G)=r$ and $\textrm{diam}(G)=s$

I tried to build it: a cycle of length $2r$ (so that the radius is $R$) then I tried to add a path that would make sure it has diameter $s$, but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Your plan sounds great.  Let's say that $r=4$ and $d=6$.  You started out with a cycle of length $8$, then what specifically would you do to it to push the diameter to $6$ while keeping the radius at $4$?

Answer (score 1):

I admit to not being sure how to make your idea work OP. I mean, it may be doable that way I at the moment can't see how. This is another idea:

1. Let $P=u_ru_{r-1}u_{r-2} \ldots u_1vv_1v_2\ldots v_r$ be a path. So $P$ has radius $r$; indeed the vertex $v$ at the midpoint of $P$ is of distance precisely $r$ from each of the two endpoints $u_r$ and $v_r$ of $P$.
2. If $s$ is even and less then $2r$ add in the edges $u_iv_{i+1}$ and $u_{i+1}v_i$, where $i$ satisfies $2(r-i)=s$; if $s$ is odd add in the edge $u_iv_i$, where $i$ satisfies $2(r-i)+1=s$.

Note that the distance in the resulting graph between $v$ and $u_r$ and between $v$ and $v_r$ remains precisely $r$. What is the diameter of the resulting graph, for $s$ satisfying $r \le s \le 2r$?

Answer (score -1):

The radius in G is the minimum eccentricity. The diameter in G is the maximum eccentricity. Let $u$ and $v$ be vertices of G such that the distance $d(u,v) = s = diam(G)$. Let $\omega$ be a central vertex so that the eccentricity $e(\omega)$ = r = rad(G). Then there exist no vertex at a distance from $\omega$ greater than r = rad(G), which means (triangle inequality): $d(w,u) + d(w,v) \leq 2.rad(G)$. Then: $r\leq s \leq 2.r$